# Send JSON body to a listening host:port

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

One system has host:port opened and listening continuously. And I am trying to send a JSON body {"name": "ravi"} to that host:port (12.345.678.12:4321).

Below is the code I tried,

```
var app = express();
const server = app.listen(4321, "12.345.678.12");
//const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

module.exports = (context, req) => {

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {

        io.emit('this', { name: "ravi"});

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            io.emit('user disconnected');
          });
    });
}
```

Please let me know, if you need more information. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless the system is running a HTTP server on port 4321 or 10001, you shouldn't use Axios.

Comment: The system is running, on the specified port. You are right, It is not a http server, may I know what should I use in place of axios?

Comment: No, I meant, does the system run a HTTP server on that port?

Comment: No, it is not. May I know what should I use in place of axios? If it is not a http server.

Comment: You can use the Node.js [Net module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), but a better option would be [Socket.io](https://socket.io) as suggested, notably because of its reliability and real-time features. You might also want to check their [docs](https://socket.io/docs).

Comment: I'll try with socket.io and let you know. Thank you. @MaximeLaunois

Comment: @MaximeLaunois I tried using socket. could you please check, if there is anything wrong.